# first segre class of a line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am reading the proof of proposition 3.1(e) in Fulton's Intersection theory book:

If $E$ is a line bundle and $\alpha \in A_*X$, then $s_1(E) \cap \alpha = -c_1(E) \cap \alpha$

The proof says

$P(E) = X$ and $\mathcal{O}_E(-1)=E$, so $s_1(E) \cap \alpha = c_1(\mathcal{O}_E(1) \cap \alpha) = -c_1(E) \cap \alpha$

I think $P(E) = X$ is because you can identify the copy of $k$ over a point $p \in X$ as the point $p$. But I don't understand why $\mathcal{O}_E(-1) = E$. Can anyone help?

Comment: For any vector bundle if $p \colon \mathbb{P}_X(E) \to X$ is the projectivization there is a tautological embedding $\mathcal{O}_E(-1) \hookrightarrow p^*E$. If $E$ is a line bundle, it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! Does the word "tautological" here means the tautological bundle? I think it is very difficult to search for the relevant info concerning tautological bundle/ canonical line bundle. Could you also suggest a reference where I can find these stuff?

Comment: "Tautological embedding" means "tautological embedding of the tautological subbundle". Its definition should come together with the definition of the projectivization of a vector bundle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sasha!